# Creating elements with "HasMany" associations does not works

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two Models:

- Roles [code](https://paste.kde.org/prkg2mobl)
- Perms [code](https://paste.kde.org/pqpd4xtt7)

I'm trying to create a bulk of *Roles* with his *permissions*:

```
function createRoles(models, cb) {

    var tree = _.map(data.Roles, function (perms, role) {
        return {
            name: role,
            perms: _.map(perms, function (perm) {
                return { key: perm };
            })
        };
    });

    /* tree:

    [ { name: 'categories_admin',
    perms: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'users_admin', perms: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'users_moderator', perms: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'questions_user',
    perms: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { name: 'questions_moderator', perms: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
      */

    models.auth.roles.bulkCreate(
        tree,
        {   include: [models.auth.perms],
            ignoreDuplicates: true }
    ).then(function (roles) {
        cb();
    }).catch(cb);
}
```

This created the roles, but the roles hasn't permissions, when I do:

```
        models.auth.roles.findAll()
            .then(function (roles) {

                roles[4].getPerms().then(function (perms) {
                    console.log("pn:", roles[4].name);
                    console.log("P", perms.length );
                });

                console.log("Roles", roles.length);
            }).catch(cb);
```

*getPerms()* don't return any result, (I tryed with various roles instances).

There are some wrong I'm doing?

PD: Sorry my poor english.